# How to start a python variable name with a "#"?

Tags: python, special-characters

I've written code that does several steps to process some files (BAM files in case you're curious but that's irrelevant to my question: http://www.broadinstitute.org/igv/BAM) to prepare them to be analyzed by software someone else wrote.

Within the code that processes the BAM files, I want to include a couple lines to build a database that logs the location and other relevant information about the processed files. This necessary for the analysis using the above-mentioned software. The way this downstream software works, there should be a header at the top of the database that begins with a `#` at the beginning of the line.

Right now, I'm trying to use a pandas DataFrame, that I later intend to write to a text file. This is an example code snippet showing, in theory, what I'm trying to do. It doesn't work because the `#` makes the rest of the line into a comment. I also tried to escape the special character by typing `\#`, but then it complains, `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character.` Does anyone have any ideas about how to get around this so that I can start off the header line of the resulting database with a `#` character.

```
import pandas as pd
I_notid_lst = ["1","3"]
II_dir = ["/exampledir/moreexmaple/fake_01.bam.by_chr", "/exmapledir/moreexample/fake_02.bam.by_chr"]

db_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(#I_notid = I_notid_lst, II_dir = II_dir_lst))
print db_df.head()
```

Comment: What you're asking for isn't a "variable name" starting with a `#`, it's a "dictionary key".

Comment: @RichieHindle: but the `dict()` constructor takes keyword parameters, which must be valid Python *identifiers*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, I know, but what the OP actually *wants* is a dictionary.  Just because you can build such a thing using identifiers doesn't mean they have to do it that way.

Comment: @RichieHindle: sure, but if you don't know about dict literal syntax it seems like using keyword arguments is the only option, so I can see where the confusion comes from.

Answer (score 3):

The `#I_notid` is not strictly a variable, but a keyword argument given to the `dict`, which is a constructor for creating dictionaries. A keyword argument like names in general can consist only of alphanumeric characters and `_`, and thus this usage allows for creation of dictionaries with only keys that are strings and that follow the python naming conventions.

However, as always, you can use the `{key: value, ...}` dictionary literal construct to create dictionaries with keys of any allowed types, and of course also with string keys that have non-alphanumeric characters:

```
db_df = pd.DataFrame({'#I_notid': I_notid_lst, 'II_dir': II_dir_lst})
```